# CakePHP 3.x - Modify user data in Auth component before session creation

Tags: authentication, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

When using the Auth component in CakePHP 3 you can define the `findAuth()` finder (or configure a different finder) to have control over what data is loaded:

```
// AppController
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    //...
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'finder' => 'auth'
        ]
    ],
    //...
]);


// UsersTable
public function findAuth($query, array $options)
{
    return $query
        ->...;
}
```

I need some functionality that cannot be done with the query builder. How can I post-process the loaded auth data before session creation?
Note that I have different ways of logging in my users, so I would prefer this be kept inside the AuthComponent logic.

(This is still for CakePHP 3, but a brief comment on how  this could be done in the new CakePHP 4 Authentication plugion would also be appriciated.)

EDIT: Rough outline of what I need: data needs to re-organised in the users array based on current context, i.e. users can have an active project selected.

Comment: In which way exactly do you need to modify the data?

Comment: Added it to question. Basically, I need to structure the users array such I can later easy get the information related to the selected project of the user.

Comment: "I would prefer this be kept inside the AuthComponent logic" -> make your own AuthComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not really sure what exactly you need to re-organize in what way exactly, but generally you can modify the queried data using mappers/reducers and result formatters, the latter usually being the easier way.

Here's a quick example that would add an additional field named `additional_data` to the result in case a field named `active_project_id` is set:

```
$query->formatResults(function (\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface $results) {
    return $results->map(function ($row) {
        if (isset($row['active_project_id'])) {
            $row['additional_data'] = 'lorem ipsum';
        }

        return $row;
    });
});
```

Such a finder query would work with the new authentication plugin too.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Adding Calculated Fields](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields)**

Comment: Good call. I'll see how this fits and get back.